# I want to replace the static code of model to dynamic

Tags: magento2, database, cart

Please someone review my code and make necessary changes in it.
Basically, i want to replace my static code to dyanmic in model.

Here's my code:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;


class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator)
    {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    }
  public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 200; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {





        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 200
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Fee');
    }
}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $rewardspointsFactory;
    protected $customerSession ;
    public function _construct(
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\RewardspointsFactory $rewardspointsFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession 
    ){
        $this->rewardspointsFactory = $rewardspointsFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function rewardPoints()
    {
         if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

            $Rewardspoints = $this->rewardspointsFactory->create();
            $collection = $Rewardspoints->getCollection();
            // customerId
            $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
            return $collection->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);

            var_dump($collection);
         }else{
             return false;
         }

    }
}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource collection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Sugarcode\Test\Model\Test', 
            'Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test');
    }
}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model;
use Magento\Cron\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Test extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $_dateTime;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test::class);
    }
}
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Test extends AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mr_dukaaniatest', 'dukaaniatest_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What and where you want to change?

Comment: I want to show dynamic values on that page /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php replace those 200 values that set on static

Comment: the value will be fetched from where? `Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection` ?

Comment: the value fetch from
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Controller/Index/Index.php

Comment: can i call data from database and show on same page sam like as:
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

Comment: understand that you want to chnages value at `home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php`  . I am asking your from which value `$exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 200; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
` this field value will be replaced?

Comment: i want to fetch values from database that ti connected and show this values on screen.
 public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 200
        ];
    }

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to call Collection class `Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection` for fetch data for mr_dukaaniatest table at  `app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee`

and then filter the collection by customer id which you will get from  **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote**

```
<?php


namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;

class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal {

    /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null;

    protected $rewardspointCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
            \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory
            ) {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
        $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory = $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 200; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    }

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */

    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {


        $rewardspointCollection = $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory->create();
        $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
        $rewardspointCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);
        if(count($rewardspointCollection) > 0){
           $firstItem =  $rewardspointCollection->geFirstItem();
           return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => $firstItem->getData('TitleFieldName'),
            'value' => $firstItem->getData('fieldName')
        ];
        }else{
            return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 0
        ];
        }



    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel() {
        return __('Fee');
    }

}
```

**You have to change**  `TitleFieldName and fieldName` repect to database field.

```
'title' => $firstItem->getData('TitleFieldName'),
'value' => $firstItem->getData('fieldName')
```

Comment: Quote is not tested . it give base on idea

Comment: error
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory does not exist
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory does not exist
Exception #2 (RuntimeException): Source class "\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection" for "Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: have u did di complie?

Comment: yes i run the di compile command as well but nothing happen